# LINQ - max of all columns - create single "row"

Tags: c#, linq

Want to do this but as a single expression:

```
var maxYearVolumes = volumes.Where(v => v.YEAR == maxYear);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.JAN_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.FEB_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.MAR_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.APR_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.MAY_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.JUN_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.JUL_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.AUG_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.SEP_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.OCT_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.NOV_VOLUME);
maxYearVolumes.Max(v => v.DEC_VOLUME);
```

Need a single "row" with these properties filled in with the max of each.

Comment: You can group on a constant `volumns.GroupBy(x => 1).Select(grp => new { JanMax = grp.Max(v => v.JAN_VOLUME), ... , DecMax = grp.Max(v => v.DEC_VOLUME) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [@juharr in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73492952/linq-max-of-all-columns-create-single-row#comment129783963_73492952), you can group by a constant, then take the max of each value

```cs
var maxYearVolumes = volumes
    .Where(v => v.YEAR == maxYear)
    .GroupBy(v => 1)
    .Select(g => new {
        Jan = g.Max(v => v.JAN_VOLUME),
        Feb = g.Max(v => v.FEB_VOLUME),
        Mar = g.Max(v => v.MAR_VOLUME),
        Apr = g.Max(v => v.APR_VOLUME),
        May = g.Max(v => v.MAY_VOLUME),
        Jun = g.Max(v => v.JUN_VOLUME),
        Jul = g.Max(v => v.JUL_VOLUME),
        Aug = g.Max(v => v.AUG_VOLUME),
        Sep = g.Max(v => v.SEP_VOLUME),
        Oct = g.Max(v => v.OCT_VOLUME),
        Nov = g.Max(v => v.NOV_VOLUME),
        Dec = g.Max(v => v.DEC_VOLUME),
    })
    .First();
```

If you are using Linq-To-Objects and are worried about performance, you can use `.Aggregate` instead, but it may be easier to just write a normal `foreach` loop.